# How to use relationships in custom attribute inside Eloquent model (Laravel)?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, model, attributes, eager-loading

Helloo

I need to do that in my Eloquent Model :

```
protected $with = ['releases'];
public function releases() { return $this->hasMany('App\Article\Release', 'article_id'); }
public function getReleasedAttribute() { return ($this->releases()->count() > 0); }
public function getContentAttribute() { return $this->releases()->orderBy('published_at', 'desc')->first()->content; }
```

But I have a lot of queries called !! What is the best solution to eager load ? I'm gonna need thoses attributes each time, so I prefer to set it up directly in my model than on the query builder in my controller

I use a custom Resource for my Json Response and here the query on my controller :

```
$articles = Article::with('releases')->has('releases')->get();
return ArticleReleasedResource::collection($articles);
```

Thx

Answer (score 4):

You can use the $appends attribute in your model
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-serialization#appending-values-to-json

```
protected $appends = ['released'];
```

Comment: Hi thx but just adding $appends will resolve my multi-queries issue ?

Comment: PS : I use Resources for my Json Response

Answer (score 0):

I resolved by myself

I listen the "created" event to push a "released" boolean on my main Model, and for the content I did :

```
public function getContentAttribute() {
    return $this->releases->sortByDesc('published_at')->first()->content;
}
```

I get the collection, sort it and get the first Model !